# date_footer using display="weekly" doesn't display correctly for entries on Sunday

Tags: channel-entries

I'm currently attempting to display a list of all entries, split into the weeks that they were published in and formatted in a table. The variable tag pair `date_heading` and `date_footer` appear to be perfect for the job and my template code is as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="order"
    limit="99999"
    status="Complete"
    dynamic="no"
}

    {date_heading display="weekly"}

        <p>Week starting {week_date format="%j/%n/%Y"}</p>

        <table>

            <thead>
                <th>Transaction ID</th>
                <th>Transaction Date</th>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

    {/date_heading}

            <tr>
                <td>{order_transaction_id}</td>
                <td sorttable_customkey="{entry_date}">{entry_date format="%d/%m/%Y"}</td>
            </tr>

    {date_footer display="weekly"}

            </tbody>
        </table>

    {/date_footer}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What I'm finding is that when an entry posted on a Sunday is output, it doesn't correctly output the date_footer. Rather, it appears after the week's footer and before the next week's heading. For example:

```
<p class="week-heading">Week starting 30/6/2014</p>

<table class="sortable" style="width: 100%; margin: 24px 0; display: none;">

    <thead>
        <th>Transaction ID</th>
        <th>Transaction Date</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1111</td>
            <td>30/06/2014</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<tr>
    <td>2222</td>
    <td>30/06/2014</td>
</tr>
```

I dug into the ExpressionEngine code that drive this and found the two following snippets in `/system/expressionengine/libraries/channel_entries_parser/components/Header_and_footer.php` for the `date_heading` and the `date_footer` respectively:

```
...
elseif ($display == 'weekly')
{
    $temp_date = $data['entry_date'];

    // date()'s week variable 'W' starts weeks on Monday per ISO-8601.
    // By default we start weeks on Sunday, so we need to do a little dance for
    // entries made on Sundays to make sure they get placed in the right week heading
    if (strtolower(ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('start_day')) != 'monday' && ee()->localize->format_date('%w', $data['entry_date']) == 0)
    {
        // add 7 days to toss us into the next ISO-8601 week
        $temp_date = strtotime('+1 week', $temp_date);
    }

    $flag_obj->heading_date_weekly = ee()->localize->format_date('%Y%W', $temp_date);

    if ($flag_obj->heading_date_weekly == $flag_obj->heading_flag_weekly)
    {
        $tagdata = ee()->TMPL->delete_var_pairs($tag, 'date_heading', $tagdata);
    }
    else
    {
        $tagdata = ee()->TMPL->swap_var_pairs($tag, 'date_heading', $tagdata);

        $flag_obj->heading_flag_weekly = $flag_obj->heading_date_weekly;
    }
}
...

...
elseif ($display == 'weekly')
{
    if ( ! isset($query_result[$data['count']]) OR
        ee()->localize->format_date('%Y%W', $data['entry_date']) != ee()->localize->format_date('%Y%W', $query_result[$data['count']]['entry_date']))
    {
        $tagdata = ee()->TMPL->swap_var_pairs($tag, 'date_footer', $tagdata);
    }
    else
    {
        $tagdata = ee()->TMPL->delete_var_pairs($tag, 'date_footer', $tagdata);
    }
}
...
```

As you can see, it appears they've applied some sort of workaround in the heading for when we set the week to start on Sunday, but not in the footer. I changed the start_week parameter to Monday, which solved the problem, however the client would like the week to start on Sunday. While I know basic PHP, this kind of stuff is still a bit away from me.

Has anyone else ever encountered this? And, if you have, have you found a workaround?

Comment: Did you report the bug?

Comment: I was hoping for there to be a workaround, so hadn't reported it before posting this. I have reported the bug now though and it can be followed [here](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20431/date_footer-with-displayweekly-doesnt-work-for-posts-published-on-a-sunday)

Comment: Thanks! But what you posted as "solution" isn't one. Let's wait to see what happens next.